# C# DWM transparent windows effect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, dwm

So I've got a project building a Windows Flip (Alt+Tab) type app to be driven using the Kinect.

I've got all my handles and thumbnails coming through nicely along with window selection and a few of my custom modifiers etc.
The last piece required for the solution is the transparency effect that Windows Flip applies to all the active windows except the selected window.
But I can't seem to find it anywhere, so I'm guessing it might not be public.

Anyone got any experience/an inkling on this?